# Using external css in html coding

Tags: html, css

Our teacher told us that we should try putting an external css file to edit my html program, I tried using the link tag but it wouldn't affect anything. I don't know if it's my html or my css that has a problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Firstly please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask first if your question is suitable to ask. About the question ; you miss " char in  href="External.css" note that this is only works if your index.html and external.css  are in the same folder.

Comment: Your HTML file and CSS file present in the same folder or different folder ?

Comment: your information is not clear enough, but you can Inspect  the page with `Cntrl + Shift + I` and see it effected or not

Comment: Check your file structure. Did you create a different folder to store your CSS? If so, you have to use the relative or absolute path on the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the link tag use proper punctuation for the **href** attribute

modify your link tag as following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="External.css">
```

You haven't closed the href attribute that is why your code is not being recognized from line-5 onwards. Use an text editor like VsCode to easily detect such errors in the future.

use https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp for further reference

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as everyone suggest you need to check on the path. From your code we suspect that the css and html are under a same directory. I have some codes to check for your reference. Hoping it would help.

Put following file into one directory and run the html

File: index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="External.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

File: External.css

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: It was saved in a different folder, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close "External.css" like this. And it will work.
Other tip
: Make sure html ,css and js are all in same folder .